# Bootstrap popovers: Use of callbacks in order to show/hide overlay -doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a web app where I use Bootstrap-popovers a number of times. These popovers contains HTML and are used to display small forms and such.
The idea is to "dim" the background with a black transparent overlay whenever a popover is shown in order to minimize distractions for the user.
I've gotten the basics down quite easily, but I really cannot get it to work as I want.

The desired functionality is: Whenever a button triggers a popover, the overlay should show in the background, covering the rest of the page.
When the popover is dismissed, either by it's save button, by it's cancel button or by a second click on the original trigger button, the overlay shall hide again.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

// loading bootstrap.css
// loading main.css
// loading jquery.min.js
// loading bootstrap.min.js
// loading main.js

</head>

<body>
<div class="fadeMe" style="display:none"></div>

// ...lots of content

<div id="newReward" class="reward-markup edit-area">
    <a href="#!" id="addRewardBtn" class="btn btn-primary trigger">
        ADD REWARD
    </a>

    <div class="head hide">
        <h4>NEW REWARD</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="content hide">

     // ...small HTML-Form which works fine

        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-left" onclick="$('.popover').popover('hide');">CANCEL</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onclick="addReward()">SAVE</button>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

MAIN CSS

```
.fadeMe
{
  opacity:0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  background-color:#000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
}
```

MAIN JS

```
$(function(){

    $(".trigger").on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        $("div.fadeMe").show();
    });
    $(".trigger").on('hidden.bs.popover', function(){
        $("div.fadeMe").hide();
    });

});

$('.reward-markup > .trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {

        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

This is not working though. Triggering the popover brings out the overlay as it should, but dismissing the popover with the original triggerbutton leaves the overlay without hiding it, and thereafter wrecks the popover functionality alltogether (cancel button functions as it should). Strange thing is though, that if you supplement the jquery show/hide calls with simple alerts, the whole things works fine with trigger button showing alerts accordingly:

```
$(".trigger").on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        alert('The popover is about to show.');
    });
$(".trigger").on('hide.bs.popover', function(){
        alert('The popover is now hidden.');
    });
```

And even more strange: If you add *both* alerts and jquery-calls trigger button will show the first alert and then the overlay, but a second click on trigger button will not show second alert and overlay will not hide:

```
$(".trigger").on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        alert('The popover is about to show.');
        $("div.fadeMe").show();
    });
$(".trigger").on('hide.bs.popover', function(){
        alert('The popover is now hidden.');
        $("div.fadeMe").hide();
    });
```

Could someone please help me understand what's going on here? It drives me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

i faced some kind of this before ... just for help if it works with you

in the cancel button instead of `.('hide');` the popover ...
just try to click the original button again like below ...

```
<button class="btn btn-warning pull-left" onclick="$('.reward-markup > .trigger').click()">CANCEL</button>
```

I hope it helps

also check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mda4bac6/) .... if it helps

Comment: Hmm, guess I could try that, but the cancel button is the only thing that works as it is.

Comment: check the fiddle if it helps ... It's just a POC of what you are doing

Comment: Tested it, and it yielded the same result as clicking the trigger button in the first place. That is, the overlay displays, but never disappears :(  Yes, the Fiddle works, but not my code. It must be something else going on in my codebase, but I cannot figure out what..

Comment: did you add some thing to the fiddle ... css or anything?

Comment: you can not click on the original button again after showing the popover because the fadeMe ..... is shown in front of the original button so you can not click on it again...

Comment: Aha, maybe that's it! I have sought to retain the normal operation of trigger/untrigger-functionality for popovers but that is not a major thing since I have a cancel-button as well..